# How to use polyfills with babel 7.4 and grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, core-js

I run into a few issues with IE11 when using babel and grunt. I need to polyfill some code using new ECMA features written by a former colleague, who updated babel to 7.4 (but does not change babelrc to use corejs) and code was not testet in IE11. So now code doesn't work in Internet Explorer, and I had to polyfill, without deeper knowledge with babel and grunt. I change babelrc preset-env to use builtIns, but can't get it to run.

I change babelrc to use preset-env with builtIns. So I set useBuiltIns to usage, so polyfills only include when needed. But then babel generates "require" statements which of course could not be interpreted by browsers. Even when I set useBuiltIns to "entry" (and I have no idea what is the difference to "usage"), I get "SCRIPT5009: "Symbol" is undefined" as error in js console in my IE11.

```
package.json:
{
  "name": "xyproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap3-dialog": "^1.35.4",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs": "^1.5.6",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-bs": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs": "^2.2.3",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.4",
    "grunt-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify-es": "^3.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.3.0",
    "grunt-notify": "^0.4.5",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.10.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0",
    "uglify-es": "github:mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "sourceType": "unambiguous",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", {
        "debug": false,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3,
        "targets": {
          "ie": "9"
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "minify", {
        "mangle": true,
        "deadcode": true,
        "simplify": true,
        "builtIns": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('../../package.json'),

    config: {
      sass:         'assets/scss',
      css:          'assets/css',
      js:           'assets/js',
      templates:    'assets/templates',
      build:        'assets/build',
      node_modules: 'node_modules'
    },

    // notify if process is done
    notify: {
      watch_js: {
        options: {
          title: 'Task Complete',
          message: 'JS Tasks are completed'
        }
      },
      watch_css: {
        options: {
          title: 'Task Complete',
          message: 'SCSS/CSS Tasks are completed'
        }
      }
    },

    // Bablify our js files - we're now able
    // to write JS code in newest style :)
    // Babel will transpile the code for elder browsers
    babel: {
      options: {
        // babelrc: false,
        // sourceType: 'unambiguous',
        // sourceMap: true,
        // presets: [
        //   [
        //     '@babel/preset-env', {
        //       targets: {
        //         ie: '9'
        //       }
        //     },
        //   ],
        //   [
        //     'minify', {
        //       mangle: true,
        //       deadcode: true,
        //       simplify: true,
        //       // evaluate: true
        //     }
        //   ]
        // ],
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= config.build %>/backend.min.js':         '<%= config.build %>/backend.min.js',
          '<%= config.build %>/backend_tables.min.js':  '<%= config.build %>/backend_tables.min.js',
          '<%= config.build %>/backend_pages.min.js':   '<%= config.build %>/backend_pages.min.js',
          '<%= config.build %>/wysiwyg.min.js':         '<%= config.build %>/wysiwyg.min.js',
          '<%= config.build %>/dataview.min.js':        '<%= config.build %>/dataview.min.js',
          '<%= config.build %>/reporting.min.js':       '<%= config.build %>/reporting.min.js',
          // '<%= config.build %>/search.min.js':          '<%= config.build %>/search.min.js',
        }
      }
    },

    build: {
      clean: {
        tasks: ['clean']
      },
      css: {
        tasks: ['sass']
      },
      js: {
        tasks: [
          'concat',
          'babel',
          'uglify',
          'remove_unnecessary_files'
        ]
      }
    },

    // removes all files from folder
    clean: ['<%= config.build %>/'],

    // compiles scss to css
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed',
          compass: false,
          loadPath: [
            'node_modules/normalize-scss/sass'
          ]
        },
        files: {
          '<%= config.build %>/main.css': [
            '<%= config.sass %>/main.scss',
            '<%= config.node_modules %>/bootstrap3-dialog/src/css/bootstrap-dialog.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    concat: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      libs: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/@babel/polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery-ui.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery.validate.js',

          // bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js
          // '<%= config.js %>/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.js',
          // '<%= config.js %>/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',

          '<%= config.js %>/libs/bootstrap.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/bootstrap-select.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/bootstrap-datepicker.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/icheck.min.js',
          // '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery.tagsinput.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery.noty.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/noty-layouts/topRight.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/noty-themes/default.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery.nestable.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/fileinput.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/moment.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/plugins.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/actions.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/jquery.cookie.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/spin.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/select2.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/icheck_custom.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/bootstrap-typeahead.min.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/daterangepicker.js',
          // if you want to add Datatatables plugins, see the following lines on how to do so:
          //          '<%= config.js %>/libs/datatables.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net-colreorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js',
          '<%= config.node_modules %>/bootstrap3-dialog/src/js/bootstrap-dialog.js',

          '<%= config.js %>/libs/lodash.min.js',

          '<%= config.js %>/libs/filesaver.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/libs/queue.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/libs.min.js'
      },
      backend: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.js %>/globals.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/backend.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/datatable.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/action.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/menu.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/validate.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/ajax.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/adv_search.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/massupdate.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/storage.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/widgets.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/sessionTimer.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/widgets.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/impersonate.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/helper/*.js'
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/backend.min.js'
      },
      pages: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.js %>/page_*.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/backend_pages.min.js'
      },
      dataview: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.js %>/dataview/*.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/dataview.min.js'
      },
      reporting: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.js %>/reporting/*.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/reporting.min.js'
      },
      tables: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.js %>/table_*.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/table_search/type_base.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/table_search/*.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/backend_tables.min.js'
      },
      /*search: {
        src: [
          // '<%= config.js %>/table_*.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/table_search/*.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/search.min.js'
      },*/
      wysiwyg: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.js %>/wysiwyg.js',
        ],
        dest: '<%= config.build %>/wysiwyg.min.js'
      }
    },

    watch: {
      options: {
        spawn: false // add spawn option in watch task
      },
      css: {
        files: [
          '<%= config.sass %>/*.scss',
          '<%= config.sass %>/*/**'
        ],
        tasks: [
          'sass',
          'notify:watch_css'
        ]
      },
      devIe: {
        files: [
          '<%= config.js %>/*.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/*/**'
        ],
        tasks: [
          'concat',
          'babel',
          'notify:watch_js'
        ]
      },
      js_dev: {
        files: [
          '<%= config.js %>/*.js',
          '<%= config.js %>/*/**'
        ],
        tasks: [
          'concat',
          // 'babel',
          // 'rename_js_files',
          'notify:watch_js'
        ]
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: true
        },
        files: ['<%= config.build %>**/*.js', '<%= config.build %>/main.css']
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' + '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */',
        sourceMap: {
          includeSources: true
        },
        report: 'gzip',
        output: {
          comments: false
        },
        sourceMapIn: function(path) {
          return path + '.map';
        }
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= config.build %>/libs.min.js': ['<%= config.build %>/libs.min.js'],
          '<%= config.build %>/backend.min.js': ['<%= config.build %>/backend.min.js'],
          '<%= config.build %>/backend_tables.min.js': ['<%= config.build %>/backend_tables.min.js'],
          '<%= config.build %>/backend_pages.min.js': ['<%= config.build %>/backend_pages.min.js'],
          '<%= config.build %>/wysiwyg.min.js': '<%= config.build %>/wysiwyg.min.js',
          '<%= config.build %>/dataview.min.js': ['<%= config.build %>/dataview.min.js'],
          '<%= config.build %>/reporting.min.js': ['<%= config.build %>/reporting.min.js'],
          '<%= config.build %>/search.min.js': ['<%= config.build %>/search.min.js'],
        }
      }
    },

    concurrent: {
      options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
      },
      dev: {
        tasks: ['watch:js_dev', 'watch:css', 'watch:livereload']
        // tasks: ['watch:js_dev', 'watch:css']
      },
      devIe: {
        tasks: ['watch:devIe', 'watch:css']
        // tasks: ['watch:js_dev', 'watch:css']
      }
    }
  });

  // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');
  // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');
  // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify-es');

  grunt.registerMultiTask('build', 'build the given task', function() {
    grunt.task.run( this.data.tasks );
  });

  grunt.registerTask('remove_unnecessary_files', 'Remove *.js to *.min.js', () => {
    let fs,
      fileNames,
      fileName;

    fs = require('fs');

    fileNames = [
      'backend_tables.js',
      'backend_tables.js.map',
      'backend_tables.min.js.map',
      'backend.js',
      'backend.js.map',
      'backend.min.js.map',
      'backend_pages.js',
      'backend_pages.js.map',
      'backend_pages.min.js.map',
      'libs.js',
      'libs.js.map',
      'libs.min.js.map',
      'main.css.map'
    ];

    for (fileName in fileNames) {
      if (fs.existsSync(grunt.config.data.config.build + '/' + fileNames[fileName])) {
        fs.unlink(grunt.config.data.config.build + '/' + fileNames[fileName], (err) => {
          if (err) {
            grunt.log.error(`Remove ${grunt.config.data.config.build + '/' + fileNames[fileName]} failed: ${err}`);
          } else {
            grunt.log.ok(`Remove ${grunt.config.data.config.build + '/' + fileNames[fileName]} done`);
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('rename_js_files', 'Rename *.js to *.min.js', function() {
    var fs,
        libsFileName,
        libsMinFileName,
        backendFileName,
        backendMinFileName;

    fs = require('fs');
    libsFileName = grunt.config.data.config.build + '/libs.js';
    libsMinFileName = grunt.config.data.config.build + '/libs.min.js';

    backendFileName = grunt.config.data.config.build + '/backend.js';
    backendMinFileName = grunt.config.data.config.build + '/backend.min.js';

    fs.rename(libsFileName, libsMinFileName, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        grunt.log.error('ERROR: ' + err);
      }
    });

    fs.rename(backendFileName, backendMinFileName, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        grunt.log.error('ERROR: ' + err);
      }
    });
  });

  // grunt.registerTask('default', ['build', 'watch:css', 'watch:js']);
  grunt.registerTask('watch:dev', ['build', 'concurrent:dev']);
  // grunt.registerTask('watch:dev-ie', ['build', 'concurrent:devIe']);
  grunt.registerTask('watch:dev-ie', ['watch:devIe', 'watch:css', 'watch:livereload']);

  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);
};
```

I am running the app with "./node_modules/.bin/grunt watch:dev-ie", then change some javascript code to trigger livereload, so "devIe" tasks are executed and babel will transpile code. If I use "entry" as value for useBuiltIn option in babelrc code works, but I get "symbol is undefined". When I use "usage" as value, then babel adds require statements to my minified js files and I get "require is undefined" in the js console.

I test the code with IE11. I do not want to use Browserify or webpack as this will make things more complex. Can anyone tell me what I am missing in my configs to make things work? I would have expected that babel does not create require statements which could not be interpreted by modern browsers and needs to be translated by webpack or something to make things work. I just want to extend my babel / grunt config to polyfill the javascript code to work in IE11 also. Maybe I am missing a package in package.json also?

Comment: any update on this?